# linq where clause with 2 datetime conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Where clause that looks like this:

```
where p.Appoint.Date > TheStartTime.Date && p.Appoint.Date < TheEndTime.Date
```

For some reason, it's returning 0. However, if I write this

```
where p.Appoint.Date == TheStartTime.Date
```

it returns a count (not the one I want though). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Say for example the dates are `2011-05-12` and `2011-05-13`. No `.Date` will be greater than the first and less than the second. At first glance, change your comparisons to `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: Have you tried p.Appoint.Date >= TheStartTime.Date && p.Appoint.Date <= TheEndTime.Date

Comment: Guys you should post those as actual answers...

Comment: ok, I added the <= and >= and now it's it's giving me more than expected. If StartTime is 5/5/2011 11:00 and EndTime is 5/6/2011 11:00 it's returning all the items that are on 5/5 and 5/6, regardless of the time of day.

Comment: @frencie, that's because that's what you tell it to do. `.Date` effectively drops the Time component (makes it 12 AM), equalizing `5/5/2011 12:00:00 AM` and `5/5/2011 11:59:59 PM`. If time *is* important, don't compare only `.Date`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I got it:

```
 a) use >= and <= 
 b) remove the .Date
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing things like this it's always easier to use Ticks

that way you're comparing between two numbers.

Comment: What's easier about `date1.Ticks < date2.Ticks` compared with `date1 < date2`?

Comment: you prefer thinking in base 12?

Comment: If you just compare two dates, there is no need to think in base 12. And, yes, I prefer thinking about actual dates to thinking about numbers such as 634408429027550057.

Answer (score 0):

Your first clause has exclusive upper and lower bounds. So for example if your lower date is 8:30 AM, this will *not* match records with an exact time of 8:30 AM, only those *later* than that.

Your second clause is looking for an exact match. If you want *inclusive* bounds, go with `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<`.